# How to select a record based on a value of relating records until null

Tags: sql, oracle

My scenario is that I have a "chain" of records relating to a previous record in the chain. The length of the chain(number of records) could be one record or two or more records.

In the example below, there are three records. The originating record in the chain will have a known ID value and NULL SOURCE. The next record's SOURCE value will be the previous record's ID. The third record's SOURCE equals the second record's ID. This trend continues until there is not an ID relating to a SOURCE.

I've written a couple of SELECTS which accomplish the same result, but I'm not really sure where to go from here to easily upscale it to a chain with potentially dozens of records whether it is how to LOOP a SELECT or some other way instead of manually writing each SELECT until no more records return. I am looking into loops, but it isn't very clear to me how to accomplish what I would like.

```
TABLE
   ID  |  COLB  |  COLC  |  SOURCE
-------------------------------------------------
ABC100 |   1    |   0    |  NULL
ABC101 |   1    |   1    |  ABC100
ABC102 |   1    |   1    |  ABC101
ABC152 |   1    |   1    |  NULL
ABC173 |   1    |   3    |  ABC152
ABC300 |   1    |   2    |  NULL
ABC301 |   1    |   3    |  ABC300
```

---

```
SELECT ID,COLB,COLC,SOURCE FROM TABLE WHERE SOURCE IN
  (SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE SOURCE IN
     (SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID='ABC123')
  );
---------------------
SELECT T3.ID,T3.COLB,T3.COLC,T3.SOURCE
FROM TABLE T1
JOIN TABLE T2 ON T1.ID=T2.SOURCE
JOIN TABLE T3 ON T2.ID=T3.SOURCE
WHERE T1.ID='ABC123';
```

---

```
RESULT
   ID  |  COLB  |  COLC  |  SOURCE
-------------------------------------------------
ABC102 |   1    |   1    |  ABC101
```

I know I can START WITH SOURCE IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR ID=SOURCE if I want to query WHERE COLB=1. That is a workaround, however, it includes all records with that COLB value, and I cannot query using WHERE ID='[value]' since it only returns the one record where it equals the ID. I would like to query using the ID and have it return the relating records in only its chain.

Any help to put me on the right path -- I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE will do:

```
with 
x (id, colb, colc, initial_id, next_source, generation) as (
  select id, colb, colc, source, id, 1 from my_table where id = 'ABC102'
  union all
  select x.id, x.colb, x.colc, t.id, t.source as next_source, x.generation + 1
  from x
  join my_table t on t.id = x.next_source
)
select id, colb, colc, initial_id
from x
where generation = (select max(generation) from x)
```

Result:

```
ID      COLB  COLC  INITIAL_ID
------  ----  ----  ----------
ABC102  1     0     ABC100
```

For reference, I used the data:

```
create table my_table (
  id varchar2(10),
  colb int,
  colc int,
  source varchar2(10)
);

insert into my_table (id, colb, colc, source) values ('ABC100', 1, 0, null);
insert into my_table (id, colb, colc, source) values ('ABC101', 1, 0, 'ABC100');
insert into my_table (id, colb, colc, source) values ('ABC102', 1, 0, 'ABC101');
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. This works! The max generation number is consistent with the LEVEL from CONNECT BY and querying all of them relating to COLB. I like that the generation also indicates how many more records there are before the final one. Thanks again!